# GSAP text animation: how to make image appear from the bottom?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I try to make a "loading page" to have animation before index page f my web site is displayed.

I start using Gsap, following tutorials.
Currently, animation on my-text works.
Now, I want my logo (an image) to appear from the bottom and end above my text.
I also want text appear with a delay from text animation.

I have try many thing like background and background image with url but doesn't works.

```
    <div class="load-container">
        <div class="images-container">
            <div class="my-img"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='header-animation'>
           <h2 id="my-text">architecture</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

#my-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 7rem;
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans';
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    line-height: 5.9rem;
    color: white;
}

.char {
    transform: translateY(115px);
    transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', loader);
const myText = new SplitType('#my-text');

function loader() {

    const TLLOAD = gsap.timeline();
    TLLOAD
        .to('#my-text', { visibility: 'visible' })
        .to('.char', {
            y: 0,
            stagger: 0.05,
            delay: 0.2,
            duration: .1
        })
        .to('.load-container', { opacity: 0, duration: 0.8, delay: 0.7 })
}
```